# A curious dependency between \newcommand and curly braces

Tags: macros, braces, grouping

An example is a bit artificial, but the point is that I do not understand why 
`{}` influence the outcome of `\newcommand` in the way described below.

Consider the following definition:

```
\newcommand\printit[1]{#1}
```

whose outcome is obvious. However, a small alteration:

```
\newcommand{\printit[1]}{#1}
```

and e.g. `\printit{2}` yields:

[image]

I have no idea why. Could you please shed some light on what is going on here?

Comment: `\def\new@command#1{%
  \@testopt{\@newcommand#1}0}` from latex.ltx, i.e. LaTeX tests whether there is an optional argument in  the first argument of `\newcommand`, i.e. `\printit[1]` and returns `0`, the `{2}` in its usage is not regarded as an argument. You could use `\printit` without `{}` and it will still print `0`, use it as `\printit[2]` and it will print `2`. In fact you have defined a macro with optional arguments in a non-obvious way

Comment: The correct syntax is `\newcommand\printit[1]{#1}` or `\newcommand{\printit}[1]{#1}` (The number of parameters to be expected is given in square brackets, _outside_ of the `{}`). In case people come across this and are confused by the above syntax.

Comment: @PeterGrill Yes, I know the correct syntax. But I was curious why grouping \printit[1] results in the (rather unexpected) outcome.

Comment: @MadHatter: Yep, I figured that. My comment was intended for others who may come across this and be confused.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If LaTeX was being written now,

```
\newcommand{\printit[1]}{#1}
```

would give an error message that `\printit[1]` was not a single token.

The correct syntax is

```
\newcommand{\printit}[1]{#1}
```

or

```
\newcommand\printit[1]{#1}
```

LaTeX does nothing special to allow both forms, it is just on the general TeX macro syntax rules that braces can be omitted if a macro argument is a single token.

If you pass two (or in this case, four) tokens to `\newcommand` then anything that happens is essentially just accidental behaviour, as the system could not really afford the space or time required to catch "unlikely" errors.

As to what happens,

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\printit[1]}{#1}

\show\printit
\expandafter\show\csname\string\printit\endcsname
\end{document}
```

produces the terminal log

```
> \printit=macro:
->\@protected@testopt \printit \\printit {0}.
l.7 \show\printit

? 
> \\printit=\long macro:
[#1]->#1.
```

The command defines `\printit` to have an optional first argument, although the default value of 0 being supplied was intended as the default value for `\newcommand` itself.
it is what makes `\newcommand\foo` the same as `\newcommand\foo[0]` and define a command with no arguments.

The inner part of the command handling the optional argument is `\\printit` which just drops the square brackets.

So

```
 \printit{2}
```

is

```
 \printit[0]{2}
```

which is

```
0{2}
```

which typesets as 02

Comment: What about LaTeX3, which is being written now? ;-)

Comment: @Socob I hadn't actually checked but add `\usepackage{xparse}` and replace `\newcommand` by `\NewDocumentCommand` and you get `! LaTeX3 Error: First argument of '\NewDocumentCommand' must be a command.`